# cron.schedule in conflict with this.knex in scheduling postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, typescript, cron, knex.js

My nodejs scolds me when I add a knex constructor ahead of the cron schedule. How can I solve this problem?

My plan is as follows: (1) perform a weekly task, which is to query the Postgresql database, (2) create an xlsx document, (3) write the query result in the document.

The program is written in Typescript, run in nodejs.

Initially the 'this' is not defined, so I add a constructor for the knex. However, after adding the constructor, the cron.schedule shows complaint that

> Member 'cron' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> 'schedule', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
>
> (for function) Parameter declaration expected.

What did I do wrong? Please advise. Thank you in advance.

```
import * as cron from "node-cron";
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import * as Knex from "knex";


export class ComplainService {
    constructor(private knex: Knex) { };
    
    **cron.schedule("* 45 23 * * 0", function()** {  //red line here//
       
        return this.knex.select('complain.complain_id').count('complain.complain_id').from('complain').groupBy('complain.complain_id'), function () {
            let workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            try {
                XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "report.xlsx");
                console.log("Write to report.xlsx successfully!");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error")
            }
        })
      
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in your syntax that it couldn't even had worked correctly before adding the constructor.

Try to code incrementally, so that you first check that simplest parts work and then add more functionality to it.

for example with steps like this:

Class declaration is correctly written:

```
export class ComplainService {
    constructor(private knex: Knex) { };
}
```

then add call to schedule:

```
export class ComplainService {
    constructor(private knex: Knex) { 
      cron.schedule("* 45 23 * * 0", function() {
        console.log('Cron runs');
      });
    }
}
```

Add simple knex request:

```
export class ComplainService {
    constructor(private knex: Knex) { 
      cron.schedule("* 45 23 * * 0", function() {
        const allComplains = await this.knex('complain');
        console.log(allComplains);
      });
    }
}
```

etc.